# How to create a new document along with metadata(columns data) in document library, when new item is added using sharepoint 2007 designer workflow?

Tags: workflow, document

Iam new to sharepoint, I need to create a workflow on a document library. Document library has columns like Employee name, EmpId,EmpDept. when a user add one item I need to create a document with Employee information, in that document library using workflow.

Please help me. Appricite your help...

Answer (score 1):

You can get some examples in the internet, how this can be achieved.

Basically these are the steps that are involved,

1. Create a content type or list to store the column data.
2. Create a document template which is reproduced in the workflow.
3. Start a workflow to initiate the process.

Visit these sites for detailed info on the same - [Example 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields.aspx) and [Example 2](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/creating-documents-with-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflows)

Comment: Hi Deepu:  Thanks alot man.It worked what exactly am looking for. I found answer at fallowing link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields.aspx

Comment: Your welcome. :)